# I'm trying to rotate an array about a given index in python

Tags: python, arrays, cyclic

case 1:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
index k=2
a[:k],a[k:]=a[k:],a[:k]
```

When I swap array elements like this. I got this output.

```
**OUTPUT:[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

case 2:

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
b[k:],b[:k]=b[:k],b[k:]
```

but when I swap array elements like this i got this.The only difference is the order of swapping.

```
OUTPUT:[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

If we swap two variables, the order of swapping doesn't make a difference.
i.e `a,b=b,a` is same as `b,a=a,b`.

Why this is not working in the case of lists/array?

Comment: The left-hand variables or slices are assigned from left to right from the right-hand tuple. If first assignment changes indexes in the list this affects the second.

Comment: Well think about the steps of what `a[:k],a[k:]=a[k:],a[:k]` does.

Comment: If you're determined to make ik work (and frustrate your coworkers) you could do `a[:k], a[len(a)//2:] = a[k:], a[:k]`

Answer (score 5):

The right hand side [is evaluated fully](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) before any assignments are done. Subsequently, the assignments are performed in left to right order.

So the first case evaluates to:

```
a[:2], a[2:] = [3, 4, 5], [1, 2]
```

The first assignment replaces the first two elements `[1, 2]` by the three elements `[3, 4, 5]`, so now we have `a == [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]`. The second assignment then replaces element 2 onwards by `[1, 2]`, so it results in `a == [3, 4, 1, 2]`.

In the second case, we have:

```
b[2:], b[:2] = [1, 2], [3, 4, 5]
```

The first assignment replaces from element 2 onwards by `[1, 2]` resulting in `b == [1, 2, 1, 2]`. The second assignment replaces the first two elements by `[3, 4, 5]`, giving `b == [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]`.

You may have noticed by now that this is rather tricky to think about and sometimes works mostly by accident, so I'd recommend simplifying the whole thing to:

```
a[:] = a[k:] + a[:k]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you swap two variables, there's no relation between two variables, then ok.
You can find the steps as following:

```py
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> k=2
>>> # a[:k], a[k:] = a[k:], a[:k]
>>> x, y = a[k:], a[:k]
>>> a[:k] = x
>>> x, a
([3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a[k:] = y
>>> y, a
([1, 2], [3, 4, 1, 2])
```